# In Alexa Response Builder, How listen user response after a directive .addAudioPlayerPlayDirective()?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

In alexa response builder, how listen user response after .addAudioPlayerPlayDirective() ?

```
return handlerInput.responseBuilder
  .speak(speechText)
  .addAudioPlayerPlayDirective(
    "REPLACE_ALL",
    "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/quizzfilm.appspot.com/o/Bientot-lepoque-viendra-ou-les-Hobbits-determineront-le-destin-de-tous.mp3?alt=media&token=7e5f570a-4e99-48a4-a473-e052d579ddcb",
    "12345"
  )
  .withShouldEndSession(false)
  .getResponse();
```

Comment: You mean what the user says after you send a PLAY directive.

Comment: Yes please ! Or how trigger another Intent ?

Comment: I want to play music ans guess the music at user ... :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot start a playback and wait for user response. Even during a playback, a user can only trigger build-in playback control intents.

---

When you send a `AudioPlayer.Play` directive with a `playBehavior="REPLACE_ALL"`, Alexa begins the playback of the specified stream, and replace current and enqueued streams. 
While sending a `Play` directive, you normally set the `shouldEndSession` flag in the response object to `true` to end the session. If you set this flag to `false`, Alexa sends the stream to the device for playback, then immediately pauses the stream to listen for the user's response.

In ask-nodejs-sdk `shouldEndSession` flag is automatically `false` if you include a `reprompt()`. As a result as soon Alexa receives this response it speaks the `speech` and `reprompt` and wait for user response (`shouldEndSession=false`). If no response is there it will end the session as usual and the **stream would never be played**.

When your skill sends a `Play` directive (`shouldEndSession` flag set to `true`) to begin playback, the Alexa service sends the audio stream to the device for playback. Once the session ends normally(when it begins playback), **Alexa remembers** that your skill started the playback and during this time, users can invoke **any of the built-in playback control intents** without using your skill's invocation name.

If you want to let the user guess a music that was played, you can use `audio` tag of SSML. So that once the audio is played, it will wait for user response.

```
<speak>
    Guess this music 
    <audio src="https://yoursoundsource.com/path/to/music.mp3" /> 
</speak>
```

**Note:** The audio file cannot be longer than ninety (90) seconds.

More on `audio` tag [here](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/speech-synthesis-markup-language-ssml-reference.html#audio).
More on `AudioPlayer` directives [here](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/audioplayer-interface-reference.html).